# How make publish by date MVC , sharepiont

Tags: asp.net, date-time, mvc, datetimecontrol

I am working in site that publish the content by date 
so, every Thursday I will compare the date that the content approved to this Thursday date
if its the same date (dependent on admin diction to publish or leave it for next week)
if its smaller it will publish auto, if its bigger it will not publish

thats what i can write

```
  public ActionResult PublishStatus(DateTime ApprovedDate)
    {
        var Approved = new AprrovedDate;
        if (Approved == DateTime.Now)
            return View(adminview);
        else if (Approved >= DateTime.Now)
            return View();
        else 
            return View();
    }
```

noted the approved date taken from list in the share-point

Comment: It's really hard to say what you want. Please add some more info. Is this an On-Premise app? If you are trying to publish something, why are you returning a View? What does that View do?